How to overlay figure caption on a image in overleaf latex?
I am using Overleaf latex. I have an input image that I cannot change/reorganize. I need to use this image to create a figure. The image itself is full page high. The left bottom of the space has enough to put a caption as shown below.

Question: How do I overlay the figure caption on the image itself to get something like below:


Is that representative of your image?  Is it one image file, or several files that you want to arrange in that manner?  If the latter, could you post the code you used to create that arrangement?  (Also, this is independent of Overleaf, and not related to latex3, so you can remove those tags.)

Yes, it's representative of my image. My image is same, just some relevant plots under the duck. It is a single image file. My code is just to load this image using \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/data_maps.png}.

I would approach this by adding a negative \vspace of the necessary height, and set the caption in a \parbox of the proper width and height.  Not tested, and there may be some side effects from setting the caption in a box.

Keep in mind that the baseline for the image is at the bottom, while the baseline for \caption is at the very top. The easy solution is to use \usepackage[export]{adjustbox} and \includegraphics[valign=T]{...}. You still need a minipage or \parbox [t or b] with the right width.

And your code is ... ?

@MS-SPO The code is exactly what I am asking help for. I have an image with some space on the bottom-left. What would be the code to put the caption there?

@skm MS-SPO is asking for the code that you used to create the top image.  That would give us something to start from.

@Teepeemm There is no code for that. That's a single image as I have already mentioned. Save the image, and there's your input. That's all I have.

Rephrased: what have you tried? You know, code is the fuel or currency in this place. Chances are, a similar question was already answered here …

@MS-SPO \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/data_maps.png}. Suggest a solution (if you have one) and I will post the result.

I think you know that a code-snippet is not what this community likes to see, do you? // In a tikzpicture environment one node can have an includegraphics as content, while an other node may give a caption a home ...
